# Google drive API - list files with its permissions

Tags: php, google-api, permissions, google-drive-api

I want to list files and its permissions by this API
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

When I set fields to ***** or explicitly set

- files(id,name,description,mimeType,parents,trashed, permissions/*))
- files(id,name,description,mimeType,parents,trashed, permissions(*))
- files(id,name,description,mimeType,parents,trashed, permissions/emailAddress)

I will never receive permissions.

I am getting this:

```
{
   "id": "abc123"
   "name": "Name of file",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "trashed": false,
   "parents": [
      "abc1234"
   ]
}
```

Also, I have noticed the API doesn't return NULL values (description), but the permission is not NULL when I fetch it by https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get.

Here is what I call in "Try this API".

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=files(id%2Cname%2Cdescription%2CmimeType%2Cparents%2Ctrashed%2Cpermissions)&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

[image]

Do anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: If you are doing this with PHP you should include your code.

Answer (score 1):

Get all permissions

```
files(id,name,description,mimeType,parents,trashed,permissions)
```

Returns.

```
 {
   "id": "1nsFyMDBDkeuLYx0oDIk9vQFOMH4Vc98ndxIG4Giq6Y",
   "name": "Copy of How to create an credentails.json",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",
   "trashed": false,
   "parents": [
    "1dIyzPuh2XFVdlhJa4wSzNTlyCRguypI"
   ],
   "permissions": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#permission",
     "id": "0603058822553437243",
     "type": "user",
     "emailAddress": "me@gmail.com",
     "role": "owner",
     "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
     "photoLink": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20=s64",
     "deleted": false
    }
   ]
  },
```

Just get the email permission

```
files(id,name,description,mimeType,parents,trashed,permissions(emailAddress))
```

returns

```
 {
   "id": "1igmEhcgLrVFyneIcwFTetsFe-eDwKDsRqTmMwHaibs",
   "name": "Copy of Copy of How to create an api key",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",
   "trashed": false,
   "parents": [
    "1yqppb5v5jSzCqnQaO8svooJh3C9nH3G"
   ],
   "permissions": [
    {
     "emailAddress": "me@gmail.com"
    }
   ]
  },
```

It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: For me not. Are you using any library? PHP?

Comment: As you have not include any code and appear to be making the calls directly i tested this in the try me section.  THis is not an issue with the api its working as intended.

Comment: I added screenshot and CURL to the main post. I am trying it with PHP library and also directly in "Try this API". No one of them works as you mentioned.

Comment: My code is from the try me as well.  It works fine.  are you sure you have authorized the proper scopes`?

Comment: @MakoBuk  Is it possible that you are in domain where there may be restricted access?

Comment: I am not sure how the Try me works. What scopes are authorized... But in PHP lib I have "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" scopes. How I said, I can retrieve permissions of files only from permission API, not from file API. The account I use is admin (owner) of all shared drives.

Comment: So are you using Oauth2 or a service account?

Comment: OAuth and desktop app.

Comment: PHP as a desktop app?

Comment: Yes. There are two types of apps (web, desktop). https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/cloud-project

Comment: @MakoBuk sorry to ask again, but are you in a Workspace domain? If so, ask your admin (of your DOMAIN, not drive) if there are restrictions on what you can see. I.e. what do you see in admin.google.com ?

Answer (score 0):

files(id, name, md5Checksum, size, parents, mimeType, webContentLink, permissionIds)

add "permissionIds" that between the returned data you will receive an array with the id of all permissions, in the case of files with "anyone" sharing the returned id is "anyoneWithLink"